# e.PreventDefault submit issue in qtip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

i am trying to get my form inside qtip tooltip to submit without loading the page. However, i can't seem to get it to stop loading the page after clicking submit. It works fine on the href but not on the submit button in the form.

```
//This One Is BROKEN 
$('#EditGallerySubmit').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

//This One Is Working Good As Expected
$('.EditGallery').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.EditGallery').each(function()
{


    $(this).qtip({
        content:  {
            text: "Loading...",
            ajax: {
                url:$(this).attr('href'),
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data, status) {   
                this.set('content.text', data);

                $('#EditGalleryForm').on('submit', function(e) {

                alert($('#EditGalleryForm').attr('action'));

                //I added this trying to fix but no luck.
                e.PreventDefault();
                });

                return false;
                }                
            }
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 100
        },
        style: 'wiki'
    });
    $(this).qtip('click', true);
});
```

THE FORM

```
    <form id="EditGalleryForm" action="Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php?action=DoEditGallery&gallerykey=<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryID']?>" method="post">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>NOTE:</b> Letters & Numbers Only</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="GalleryName" size="30" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryName']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="OriginalGalleryName" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryName']?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="GalleryID" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryID'] ?>">
            <input id="EditGallerySubmit" type="submit" name="EditGallery" value="Edit Gallery">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Try onclick="e.preventDefault();" on the button's markup and see if it works in preventing the submit.

Comment: Try return false; inside submit handler

Comment: which is your form id ?

Comment: I added my html code in the post. I already tried return false. I will try the onclick now. FormID=EditGalleryForm SubmitButtonID = EditGallerySubmit

Comment: I just tried the onclick method and it still loads the action page. Kind of weird issue.

Comment: wow, i fixed it. The problem was i had the e.preventDefault() with a uppercase P. i changed it to lowercase and that fixed the problem.

Comment: So why did "return false:" not work? Kind of weird.

Comment: Not sure, i had tried that already and the page would still load. I thank you guys for your responses and taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are attaching submit event with your submit button. Attach form id to submit event

```
$('#EditGalleryForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I think this may help you

Comment: I do appreciate your time, i tried your method and still get the same results. It should work. You suppose the problem could be 2 PreventDefaults in one qtip tooltip? The first one is for href so the tooltip loads on hover and not when clicked, the second is after the tool loads the form, so it handles form submission inside the tooltip

Comment: You are attaching submit event to submit button. Instead attach event to form. Try the above answer

Comment: The problem was in the success function i had e.preventDefault() with a uppercase P .. i changed it to a lowercase p and it fixed the problem. I do thank you for your assistance.